# `vagrant up` が `failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory` で失敗する

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

`vagrant up`を実行すると以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open  /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component   HostNetworkInterface, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleCreate(HandlerArg*, int, int*)" at line 66 of     file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

VirtualBox, Vagrantをアンインストール&インストールしても効果はありません。

Issue の "[Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory #1671](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1671)" を参考にして、

```
$ sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.virtualbox.startup.plist
```

を実行してしてみたものの、これも効果がありません。

ただ、すべての仮装マシンの `vagrant up` に失敗するわけではなく、通常通り `vagrant up` できる仮想マシンもあります。ですから、恐らく問題があるのは VirtualBox や Vagrant 側ではないと考えられます。

しかし、ここから先どのようなアプローチをすれば良いのか分かりません。
お力添え頂けるとありがたいです。

開発環境:

- VirtualBox 4.3.20
- Vagrant 1.7.1
- OS X Yosemite 10.10.1

Comment: `sudo launchctl load /Library/La...` を実行して何が表示されたかがわかるとさらに突っ込んで考えられるかもしれません。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます!
`sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart`
ですが、そもそもApplication Supportディレクトリ配下にVirtualBoxというフォルダーがないため上手くいきませんでした。
幾つかのサイトにVirtualBox4.3以降は`$ sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.virtualbox.startup.plist`で解決するとの記述があり、これを実行しました。

Comment: @HiroshiYamamoto `sudo launchctl load /Library/La...`を実行後は、特に何も表示されませんでした！

Comment: ああ、それは重要な情報です。(　`...` は略したつもりでした。コマンドではないです。)

Comment: @HiroshiYamamoto　すみません。`...`は私も省略のつもりで引用しました。実際は正しくコマンドを入力しています！

Comment: 何も表示されない場合は、リロードが成功していることになりますね… 逆の意味になります。

Comment: だめなら、Mac を再起動してからコマンドを打つことで直る可能性もアリ。

Comment: チャットのような状態になったので、ここでコメントしないようにしましょう。 Q-zi さん 1ポイントしかないのでチャットにも参加できないのね。。。

Answer (score 1):

提示していただいた [Issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1671) の他にも、解決方法は、"[SO: vagrant up failed, /dev/vboxnetctl: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149546/vagrant-up-failed-dev-vboxnetctl-no-such-file-or-directory)" にまとまっていました。

Mac OS X のバージョンによって、ファイルの場所に違いがあるようですので、その方法だとファイルが見つからないとなったようです。　Stackoverflow の回答を参考にしつつ、以下のようなコマンドを試してみてください。

- `sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart`
- `sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox start`
- `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.virtualbox.startup.plist` <= これがダメだった
- `sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart`

Comment: `sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart`を実行してみたところ反応がありました。
`Unloading VBoxUSB.kext
(kernel) Can't unload kext org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB; classes have instances:
(kernel)     Kext org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB class org_virtualbox_VBoxUSB has 2 instances.
(kernel)     Kext org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB class org_virtualbox_VBoxUSBClient has 3 instances.
Failed to unload org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB - (libkern/kext) kext is in use or retained (cannot unload).
Error: Failed to unload VBoxUSB.kext
Unloading VBoxDrv.kext
(kernel) Can't remove kext org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv; ....`

Comment: VirtualBox が何かの原因で落とせないようです。 `kextstat -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB` の出力はどうですか？割と Mac 再起動で直る問題かもしれない。

Comment: 以下のように出力されました！
`Index Refs Address            Size       Wired      Name (Version) <Linked Against>
  130    0 0xffffff7f829e5000 0x8000     0x8000     org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB (4.3.20) <128 105 39 7 5 4 3 1>`

Comment: 問題なさそう。単純に、他に仮想マシンが起動してるのが原因かとおもいます。`VBoxManage list vms` では？（ちょっと今実機がないのでコマンドがうろ覚え）

Comment: 停止するのは、 `sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox` もしくは、 `/Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox` で出たウィンドウで（うろ覚え)、 実行中の VM を全て停止させるのが楽かも。（あとできたらどこかのタイミングで Mac を再起動してください）

Comment: 全てのVMを停止させた上で`sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart`を実行してみましたが、結果は変わりませんでした。
また、`vagrant up`も同じく失敗してしまいます。
再起動もしてみましたが結果は変わりませんでした！

Comment: 実行するのは `sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart` もしくは、 `sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox start` のほうです。そのコマンドはファイルが見つからないエラーが出ていると思います。

Comment: その２通りのコマンドですと、`...VirtualBox: command not found`になってしまいます...先ほどご回答いただいた４つのコマンドで唯一反応があったのが`sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart`でした。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。僕の入力ミスで`sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart`と間違って表記してしまっていました...修正させていただきます。

Comment: そのコマンドは「そもそもApplication Supportディレクトリ配下に VirtualBox というフォルダーがないため上手くいきませんでした。」とのことでしたので失敗したのかと考えていました。私から今の段階でいえるのはここまでです。後で、自分の環境で試してみますね。（コメントが長くなったので、この一連のやりとりはいずれチャットに移動させるか、できなければ良い回答がついた後に回答を削除します。）もしかしたらこのやり取りをみて、だれかがいい回答をしてくれるかもしれませんし！

Comment: 正しくは`sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart`コマンドを入力したところ、`Unloading VBoxUSB.kext (kernel) Can't unload kext org.virtualbox.kext....`の出力が出ました！

Comment: お手数をお掛けしてしまい申し訳ありません。確認してみたところ、cd /Users/ユーザー名/Library/Application\ Supportには、VirtualBoxフォルダが無かったのですが、cd /Library/Application\ SupportにはVirtualBoxフォルダがありました。